# Definite integral with exponential and algebraic functions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, contour-integration

I came across definte integral:-

$I(a, b) = \int_{a-b}^{a+b} \frac{1}{e^x -1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(x-a)^2/b^2}} ~\mathrm{d}x $

Mathematica was not able to guide a closed form solution, but I am hoping one exists.

What possible methods to attack such an integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not a closed form, it's possible to express this integral as a series.

Making a substitution:

$$x=by+a$$

We obtain:

$$I(a,b)=b \int_{-1}^1 \frac{dy}{(e^{by+a}-1)\sqrt{1-y^2}}$$

Now we use geometric series under the integral:

$$I(a,b)=b \int_{-1}^1 \frac{e^{-by-a}dy}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} e^{-k by-k a}=b \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-(k+1)a} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{e^{-(k+1)by}dy}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}$$

The integrals inside can be expressed as a modified Bessel function of $0$th order:

$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{e^{-(k+1)by}dy}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}=\pi I_0 \left((k+1)b \right)$$

Finally we obtain:

> $$I(a,b)=\pi b \sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-ka} I_0 (kb)$$

**Important:** the series converges only for $a>|b|$, as can be seen from the original integral expression (because the limits are both negative and positive).